# Matlab: Out of memory error using Find(), why?

Tags: matlab

I have a sparse matrix `M(290k,230k)`, the size is about 640MB (checked via `whos`).

The following instruction:

```
find(M > 0 & M<=10);
```

produces an "Out of memory" error and I don't understand why, there is plenty of memory still available, and the list of indexes having values between 0 and 10 can't be bigger than the size of the matrix itself. Am I missing something? I guess so.

EDIT:

I assumed that `M > 0` was executed before `M<=10` (as it happens in other programming languages) but I think I was wrong, in fact:

```
temp = find(M > 0)
find(M(temp) < 10)
```

doesn't produce any error, but I can't get the original indeces of M.

Since my final goal is to set 0 all the values < 10, I rewrite my question.

Having a big and very sparse matrix `M(290k,230k)` how can I set to 0 all the values < 10 without using slow loops?

EDIT 2, in reply to @AnderBiguri's code:

I have tried your code, without the modification to Mnew=sparse(zeros(size(M))) I get "out of memory", but this is understandable. The weird thing is that, even if your code makes sense, I am getting "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." on this line :

```
Mnew(ii(notdelete),jj(notdelete))=nz(notdelete);
```

I don't understand why, here is the result of a `whos` just before the assignment:

> ii         39701898x1                 317615184  double
>   jj         39701898x1                 317615184  double
>   M          290621x232537              1860320  double     sparse
>   Mnew       290621x232537            637090672  double     sparse
>   notdelete  39701898x1                  39701898  logical
>   nz         39701898x1                 317615184  double

everything makes sense to me, since the number of nonzero elements of `M` is 39701898. If I try your code on a small test matrix, everything works as expected, with the original matrix I get that error. Is there a way to debug this kind of errors?

EDIT 3: some code to reproduce the error

```
R = sprand(29062,23253,5.8748e-04);
[ii,jj,nz]=find(R);
notdelete=nz>0.5;
R2=sparse( size(R,1), size(R,2) );
R2(ii(notdelete),jj(notdelete))=nz(notdelete);
```

Comment: My guess is that the logical operators are converting M into non-sparse matrix. Probably the M<=10, as a sparse matrix is prctically fully popullated by zeros, M<=10 will be a full matrix full of 1. For the shake of testing try if `find(M>0&M>10)` trhows an error

Comment: @AnderBiguri The logical operators all produce sparse arrays.  I think that the number of matching elements is just huge.... but the size is only 640MB... hmm.

Comment: @chappjc The M<10 will return a sparse matrix, populated by 1,s everywhere (at least ever 0 of the sparse matrix). This will get the computer out of memory. I tried it and my laptop chrased.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Oh, yeah the less than 10 part would do that.  Haha!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried > 10 and it works, I had the same feeling you have but the first part (M > 0) should fix it, I don't understand.

Comment: @Eugenio Check my new update!

Comment: @Eugenio That is strange. Can you post a minimum working example with that eeror? else, can you somehow, post that sparsematrix somewhere so we can try?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've posted the code to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Eugenio oh, I feel like an idiot, I made a bi mistake in matrix indexing. Fixed the code, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is when doing `M<=10`

try:

```
M=sparse(eye(3))
M<=10

ans =

   (1,1)        1
   (2,1)        1
   (3,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
   (2,2)        1
   (3,2)        1
   (1,3)        1
   (2,3)        1
   (3,3)        1
```

Congrats! now you have a sparse matrix fully populated! you are now using the memory of a full matrix+the memory of the index of the nonzero entries! This is why it crashes. I recomend you to usedifferent approach for searching your solution.

So, if you want to delete the smaller than 0 values, you can do something like:

```
% Example matrix
M=sparse(diag([1 11 4]))
sizeM=size(M);

% findnonzero elements and indexes
[ii,jj,nz]=find(M);

% Delete it if you are worried about memory
clear M

% Get the ones you want to keep
notdelete=nz>10;

% Create a new matrix with those
Mnew=sparse(sizeM);


indx=sub2ind(sizeM,ii(notdelete),jj(notdelete));
Mnew(indx)=nz(notdelete);
```

How this code works:

what I do is describe the Spares matrix `M` as Sparse matrices are described internally: the index of the values that are non zero (`ii`,`jj`) and the values itself, `nz`.

Then I find the nonzero values that follow a rule and you want to keep (you could do the opposite and the a logical not, but I decided to do it this way). The ones you want to keep are `nz>10`. If you perform that operation in Matlab, it will give you a logical array with `1` in the ones you want to keep and `0` in the ones you don't.

Then, an empty spares matrix is created (indeed I had an error there and you correctly spotted and corrected it in the comments below). That empty Matrix is the filled with the `nz` you want to keep, so `nz(notdelete)`. Identically, for accessing the matrix only the indexes of these wanted elements need to be used, therefore `ii(notdelete),jj(notdelete)`. I hope it is more clear now

---

However, make sure you understand what you are doing. you state that

> I assumed that M > 0 was executed before M<=10 (as it happens in other
>   programming languages) but I think I was wrong

Actually M>0 IS executed before M<=10. The left to right execution applies as in other programing  languages. However, what you are doing is `(M>0) & (M<=10)`, therefore both left and right parts of the `&` need to be evaluated before the `&` itself. Indeed the left one will be evaluated first, saved in an auxiliar internal variable, but then the right part will be executed and saved into another auxiliar internal variable so in the end the logical `and` can be applied on these two auxiliar variables.

Comment: The filter I used is actually different: M > 0 & M<=10, I added the M > 0 in order to solve the problem you mentioned. Try yourself.

Comment: The result of `M > 0 & M<=10` may be the one you want, but how is that evaluated in Matlab? certainly no tin one go. Probably the left side and the rigth side are computed first, and then the `&` is computed with the result. In that middle step is when `M<=10` is evaluated, and therefore the out of memory error. @Eugenio

Comment: I assumed a left to right execution but probably I was wrong, I edited my question with more details.

Comment: @eugenio it is executed like in other programing languages.  But as in other programing languages, both left and right need to be evaluated first.  Else you would expect first  M>0, then (ans)&M and then ans<=M?.

Comment: e.g. in PHP: if ($s > 0 && $t >0)...if $s is <= 0 the second part of the if statement is not evaluated. I thought it was the same here, if an element of the matrix is not > 0 it makes sense to skip the right part, but I don't know what actually happen during the execution of a Matlab script.

Comment: About your code: with notdelete=nz>10; you meant notdelete=find(nz>10)? If yes, I get Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch when I fill Mnew, and it makes sense because notdelete contains values higher than the ii and jj max indeces, am I missing something?

Also, this part Mnew=sparse(zeros(size(M))); needs to be changed in Mnew=sparse(size(M,1),size(M,2)); otherwise I get "out of memory" (I guess the full matrix is created first and then made it sparse).

Comment: @Eugenio No, I dont meant find(nz>10). The piece of code I posted works by itself, why dont you try it?

Comment: I've tried your code without find() and explained the result in my original question as EDIT 2.

Comment: your code seems OK to me, you are right, the first version mixed together two indexing methods, however I waited to reply here because I wanted to see the results of the script. After days of computing on my laptop, the script hasn't finished yet. It is strange because when I created the original matrix I am working on, it took much less time. I created it directly with something like M = sparse(i,j,s,m,n,nzmax), though. What do you think about?